# Regex 301 Redirect .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I need to redirect ALL instances of `example.com/privacy-policy` to a new domain page.

For example, redirect `example.com/privacy-policy` AND `example.com/subfolder/privacy-policy`

This is what I have:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/privacy-policy/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$  https://new.example/privacy-policy/v2/
```

I'm not having any luck and I'm struggling with other versions of this.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try https://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: Redirects in `.htaccess` are better suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com (not ServerFault).

Comment: This forum is widely used for questions on htaccess, mod_rewrite and regex hence there is nothing wrong in asking it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule with a tweak in your regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /privacy-policy(/.*)?$  https://new.example/privacy-policy/v2/
```

- By removing `^` from regex we are now matching `/privacy-policy` anywhere in URI not just the start.
- Since you don't care what comes after `/privacy-policy`, there is no reason to match anything but optional `/.*` in the end.
- Make sure to use a new browser for your testing.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  I don't want to violate any forum rules here, but you can you briefly explain the error in my syntax vs yours?  If not, thanks again!